# Emergency remount does not prevent damaged filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have following script that performs an emergency shutdown that needs to take 1-2 seconds. (halt takes too long)

```
# Enable System Requests
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
#sync
sudo echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger
#emergency remount
sudo echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger
#shutoff
sudo echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

During this emergency shutdown, I looked at `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and saw that the emergency sync as well as the emergency read-only remount was sucessful.

But after the system is turned on again, fsck reports a file system error (`systemd status systemd-fsck-root.service` shows the error "**nodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found**").

What can I do to prevent that? I thought that the combination sync + remount is safe. I cannot explain why the file system is in an inconsistent state.

**Update:** Very weird is that if I repair the error (using boot parameter `fsck.repair=yes`), the folder /lost+found is empty and `journalctl -u systemd-fsck*` does not show that a repair was done:

```
[23:41]root@ras3:/daten/scripts$ journalctl --all -u systemd-fsck*
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 18:16:43 CET, end at Sat 2019-07-06 23:45:20 CEST. --
Jul 06 23:03:10 ras3 systemd-fsck[139]: e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
Jul 06 23:03:10 ras3 systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Jul 07 01:17:01 ras3 systemd-fsck[143]: Durchgang 1: Inodes, Blöcke und Größen werden geprüft
Jul 07 01:17:26 ras3 systemd-fsck[143]: Durchgang 2: Verzeichnisstruktur wird geprüft
Jul 07 01:17:32 ras3 systemd-fsck[143]: Durchgang 3: Verzeichnisverknüpfungen werden geprüft
Jul 07 01:17:32 ras3 systemd-fsck[143]: Durchgang 4: Referenzzähler werden überprüft
Jul 07 01:17:33 ras3 systemd-fsck[143]: Durchgang 5: Zusammengefasste Gruppeninformation wird geprüft
Jul 06 23:03:43 ras3 systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
Jul 06 23:03:44 ras3 systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1...
Jul 06 23:03:44 ras3 systemd-fsck[290]: fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Jul 06 23:03:44 ras3 systemd-fsck[290]: /dev/mmcblk0p1: 188 files, 45366/86467 clusters
Jul 06 23:03:44 ras3 systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1.
```

The system is a Debian Stretch on an Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

Comment: Edit your question and show thr error.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the error message ("nodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found")

Comment: Thank you for the hint with "--all", I didn't knew that.  The revealed blob data (I have updated my question) just shows the default status messages "step 1, 2, 3, 4", no errors. (In German e.g. "Durchgang 2: Verzeichnisstruktur wird geprüft"). I think it is BLOB data, because there are German umlauts (äöüß) in it.

Comment: @DanielMarschall another side-note: that shouldn't happen if you use e.g. `de_DE.utf8` locale. If possible, I invite you to join our glorious Unicode future :-). If you need to transcode existing filenames, I think you can use `convmv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens.  Here is an untested alternative.  I hope this will also run in just a few seconds on your system.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/emergency-poweroff.service
#
# Immediately terminate all processes, and then power off.
# Usage: systemctl start emergency-poweroff

[Unit]
Description=Emergency Power-Off
DefaultDependencies=no
Type=oneshot

# SIGKILL all the things
# - except the process itself, or we would not continue
ExecStart=/sbin/killall5 -9

# Wait for all processes to be cleaned up,
# then cleanly shutdown the filesystems and kernel.
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl poweroff --force
```

If you replace `systemctl poweroff` with `systemctl halt`, it *might* retain the log messages on-screen.  That might be useful as a first test.